# can you run an ember.js app inside an ember.js app

Tags: ember.js

We have a theoretical need to run an ember widget inside of another ember widget. Is this possible to do? Would scoping the nested ember widget to a different dom element than its parent work?

The idea is that we might need to embed our ember widgets on customer websites that also run ember.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand you correctly but If your need is to have separate components that you can distribute and reuse across application, you sure can have them. Although I'm not sure I got you right as you seem to speak of 2 different problems (nesting widgets and distributing ember widgets as third parties for other ember applications...)

Here is a [fiddle on how to make an external component](http://jsfiddle.net/Sephy/f7A8y/) and reuse it if you want more details. Let me know if this helps.

The component :

```
var GravatarImageComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    size: 200,
    email: '',

    gravatarUrl: function () {
        var email = this.get('email'),
            size = this.get('size');

        return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + CryptoJS.MD5(email) + '?s=' + size;
    }.property('email', 'size')
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "gravatar-image-component",
  initialize: function(container, application) {
      container.register('component:gravatar-image', GravatarImageComponent);
  }
});
```

The HTML to bring it to life :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <ul class="example-gravatar">
      <li>{{gravatar-image email="tomster@emberjs.com" size="200"}}</li>
      <li>{{gravatar-image size="200"}}</li>
    </ul>

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/gravatar-image">
    <img {{bind-attr src=gravatarUrl}}>
    <div class="email-input">
      {{input type="email" value=email placeholder="tomster@emberjs.com for instance"}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: The question was more along the lines of your statement "distributing ember widgets as third parties for other ember applications". If I have an ember application and I want to embed it in a portal/website that is already running ember with its own "widgets", is there a way to easily do that.